# How to remove specific activity from the stack

Tags: android, launch

Lets put we 3 activates that may follow the stack **A->B->C**

How can I close **A** and keep **B->C**, but **only** if **B** opens **C**?

**C** is not always opened, but if it gets opened only then **A** should be removed, leaving the stack as **B->C**. Otherwise will remain as **A->B**.

I don't see the possibility of using **finish()** in **A**, as it should be closed from **B** when opening **C**.

By the way **A** is a single instance with its own affinity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write an `abstract` `BaseActivity` class and implement a `LocalBroadcastManager` in it and register a `BroadcastReceiver`. Note that we have also introduced an abstract `onFinishReceived` method.

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  private LocalBroadcastManager mLBM;
  private final BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      onFinishReceived(intent.getStringExtra("activity"));
    }
  }

  protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    mLBM = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this);
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(...);
    mLBM.registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
  }

  protected void onDestroy() {
    mLBM.unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    mLBM = null;
  }

  abstract void onFinishReceived(String activity);
}
```

Then, extend all `A`, `B` and `C` Activities from the `BaseActivity` and override the `onFinishReceived()` method.

```
public class A extends BaseActivity {

  void onFinishReceived(String activity) {
    if (activity.equals("A") { // or "B" or "C"
        finish();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now, whenever you want to finish a specific activity use,

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context)
    .sendBroadcast(new Intent()
        .setAction(...)
        .putExtra("activity", "A") // or "B" or "C"
    );
```

---

`LocalBroadcastManager` is now deprecated. It's better if you can use something like `RxJava`. The idea is to use an asynchronous and event-based mechanism rather than going for a simple ugly solution like storing the Activity in a static variable.

Comment: Quite a good idea